# Оптимизировать функцию Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. Делаю небольшой проект на Ларавел, где нужно сгенерировать 4 случайные дни недели , включая сегодняшний. Моя функция правильно работает, но выглядит не ахти. Может кто-то подскажет более изящный вариант?

```
  public function getRandomDays()
    {
        $key = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
        $data = Arr::random($key, 3);
        $days[] = now()->isoFormat('dddd');
        $days[] = now()->addDay($data[0])->isoFormat('dddd');
        $days[] = now()->addDay($data[1])->isoFormat('dddd');
        $days[] = now()->addDay($data[2])->isoFormat('dddd');
        $days = collect($days)->shuffle();

        return $days;
    }
```

Comment: Вряд-ли это более изящно, но можно не вручную в массив  days добавлять данные,  а прогнать в цикле массив $data

Comment: Или наоборот как вариант обойтись без массива $data вообще  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737423/getting-random-date-between-two-dates